# How do I reference System.Span<T> in my dotnet core project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Everybody seems to suggest that it's already available, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get `System.Span<T>`.

The [documentation says ".Net Core 2.0"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.0), and [this post from Mads Torgerson](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/welcome-to-c-7-2-and-span/) suggests that it shipped with VS 15.5, and we're up to VS 15.5.2, so it must be public for somebody. But I'm working on a mac, and using dotnet core to build my project.

`dotnet --version` reports `2.1.2`. My project is super simple:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And yet, for all I do, I can't reference `System.Span<T>`. What am I missing?

Comment: It is a C# **7.2** feature and you have to ensure to use C# **7.2**

Comment: How? I don't have a C# version anywhere in my project.

Comment: Of course you have, but it is set per default to C# **7(.0)**

Comment: Edited: `dotnet build` accepts `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` and `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>`, but neither solves my problem.

Comment: @JohnDoty does duplicate question help to solve it?