# How to use Span in Convert.TryFromBase64String()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, base64

I was trying to write some `try catch` for `Convert.FromBase64String()` and I found out that it already has `TryFromBase64String()` method. But it needs 3 arguments:

```
public static bool TryFromBase64String(string s, Span<byte> bytes, out int bytesWritten);
```

So how can I use `Span<byte> bytes` there?

I only found this in docs, but without proper description. Maybe this is too obvious.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tryfrombase64string?view=netcore-2.1

Thank to @Damien_The_Unbeliever and [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) article I found out more about `Span`. So...

Span is used for saving memory and don't call GC so much. It can store arrays or portion of array, but I still can't figure out how to use it in that method.

Comment: `Span<T>` is a new type in .NET. There are entire [articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) to read about it.

Comment: It belongs to `System.Span<T>` type, a C# 7.2 feature. Check for similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849352/how-do-i-reference-system-spant-in-my-dotnet-core-project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As written in the linked questions, `System.Span<T>` is a new C# 7.2 feature (and the `Convert.TryFromBase64String` is a newer .NET Core feature)

To use `System.Span<>` you have to install a nuget package:

```
Install-Package System.Memory
```

Then to use it:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[((b64string.Length * 3) + 3) / 4 -
    (b64string.Length > 0 && b64string[b64string.Length - 1] == '=' ?
        b64string.Length > 1 && b64string[b64string.Length - 2] == '=' ?
            2 : 1 : 0)];

int written;
bool success = Convert.TryFromBase64String(b64string, buffer, out written);
```

Where `b64string` is your base-64 string. The over-complicated size for `buffer` should be the exact length of the buffer based on the length of the `b64string`.

Comment: It always return false. I have my `var b64string = "individualtest@email.com"` encoded in base 64 (hash `aW5kaXZpZHVhbHRlc3RAZW1haWwuY29t`) and I get false.

Comment: @Morasiu can't test until this evening. Away from computer. But it should be `var b64string = "aW5kaXZpZHVhbHRlc3RAZW1haWwuY29t"`

Comment: Okay, no problem. I will try resolve by myself then. It is actually `var b64string = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("individualtest@email.com"));`

Comment: Ok, it worked! But is there a way to make this buffer declaration more simple? And do I need `written` for something?

Comment: @Morasiu If it is ok for you to have an overlong buffer, then `new byte[b64string.Length * 3 / 4]` will have up to 2 extra bytes. You'll have to use the `written` to know how many byte were written. Note that even with the overlong version, spaces in the middle of the b64 string (like `"aW5 
   kaX    ZpZHVhbHRlc3RAZW1haWwuY29t"`) will cause the `byte[]` to be not fully used.

Comment: Ok, so I'll just extract that ugly declaration and forget. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach, using [ArrayPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-6.0) (to reduce [GC pressure](https://adamsitnik.com/Array-Pool/)), if you need the buffer only temporarily:

```
// Minimum length that is guaranteed to fit all the data.
// We don't need the exact length, because the pool
// might return a larger buffer anyway.
var minLength = ((value.Length * 3) + 3) / 4;
var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(minLength);
try
{
    // (buffer is implicitly cast to Span<byte>)
    if (Convert.TryFromBase64String(value, buffer, out var bytesWritten))
    {
        // do something with it...
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesWritten);
    }
    throw new FormatException("Invalid base-64 sequence.");
}
finally
{
    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
}
```

For even better GC efficiency and small buffer sizes, have a look at [stackalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc).

Answer (score 6):

You could use it like this, making use of all the `TryFromBase64String` arguments:

```
public string DecodeUtf8Base64(string input)
{
  var bytes = new Span<byte>(new byte[256]); // 256 is arbitrary

  if (!Convert.TryFromBase64String(input, bytes, out var bytesWritten))
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The input is not a valid base64 string");
  }

  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.Slice(0, bytesWritten));
}
```

Comment: You could make this better performance using `stackalloc`...  Try `Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[256];`

Comment: @marsze - You're right, that you do not want to pass a possibly large array length into `stackalloc`.  [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc) for `stackalloc` give an example on how to handle this.

Assuming you've defined: `const int MaxStackLimit = 1024;`  Then you can select the appropriate allocation mode depending on requested length:

`Span<byte> buffer = inputLength <= MaxStackLimit ? stackalloc byte[MaxStackLimit] : new byte[inputLength];`

Answer (score 3):

I used it like this:

```cs
string base64String = 'somebase64';

Span<byte> bytesBuffer = stackalloc byte[base64String.Length];

if (!Convert.TryFromBase64String(base64String, bytesBuffer, out int bytesWritten))
{
    return false;
}

ReadOnlySpan<byte> actualBytes = bytesBuffer[..bytesWritten];
```

UPDATE:

more precise way to count bytes

```
const int bitsEncodedPerChar = 6; 

int bytesExpected = (base64String.Length * bitsEncodedPerChar) >> 3; // divide by 8 bits in a byte
```

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648

Comment: +1 for the bit-shift part. I'll use that now when needing to calc decoded size. It's sometimes a few more than actual, but should be faster than the traditional formula: (3 * (content length / 4)) - (number of "=" padding characters), since it's not determining padding characters and not using division.